# JUnit testing java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, queue

I am in Eclipse Java Mars and I am having a few difficulties with JUnit testing. I am testing for my QueueADT class that I implemented with a Linked List. I will attach all 3 codes.

The problem is that I keep getting a NullPointer Exception for all of the methods in the JUnit test.

The lines that give the errors in Queue Testing are: 
All are lines with "q.enqueue" 
Line 29
Line 56
Line 67
Line 45
Line 12
Line 73
Line 36
Line 20

The QueueADT code:

```
/**
* QueueADT defines the interface to a queue collection. 
*/
public interface QueueADT<String>
{
/**  
 * Adds one element to the rear of this queue. 
 * @param element  the element to be added to the rear of the queue  
 */
public void enqueue(String element);

/**  
 * Removes and returns the element at the front of this queue.
 * @return the element at the front of the queue
 */
public String dequeue() throws CollectionUnderflowException;

/**  
 * Returns without removing the element at the front of this queue.
 * @return the first element in the queue
 */
public String first() throws CollectionUnderflowException;

/**  
 * Returns true if this queue contains no elements.
 * @return true if this queue is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty();

/**  
 * Returns the number of elements in this queue. 
 * @return the integer representation of the size of the queue
 */
public int size();

/**  
 * Returns a string representation of this queue. 
 * @return the string representation of the queue
 */
public String toString();
}
```

LinkedListQueue code:

```
/**
 * LinkedQueue represents a singly linked list implementation of a Queue. 

 */
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedQueue<String> implements QueueADT<String>
{
private int count;                // the number of items in the queue
private Node<String> head, tail;  // references to the first and last nodes in the queue

/**
 * Creates an empty queue.
 */
public LinkedQueue()
{
    count = 0;
    head = tail = null;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified element to the tail of this queue.
 * @param element the element to be added to the tail of the queue
 */
public void enqueue(String element)
{
    Node<String> node = new Node<String>(element);

    if (isEmpty())
        head = node;
    else
        tail.next = node;

    tail = node;
    count++;
}

/**
 * Removes the element at the head of this queue and returns a
 * reference to it. 
 * @return the element at the head of this queue
 * @throws CollectionUnderflowException if the queue is empty
 */
public String dequeue() throws CollectionUnderflowException
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new CollectionUnderflowException("Queue is empty.");

    String result = head.element;
    head = head.next;
    count--;

    if (isEmpty())
        tail = null;

    return result;
}

/**
 * Returns a reference to the element at the head of this queue.
 * The element is not removed from the queue.  
 * @return a reference to the first element in this queue
 * @throws CollectionUnderflowException if the queue is empty
 */
public String first() throws CollectionUnderflowException
{
    if (isEmpty())
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");

    return head.getElement();
}

/**
 * Returns true if this queue is empty and false otherwise. 
 * @return true if this queue is empty 
 */
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return(count == 0);
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");
}

/**
 * Returns the number of elements currently in this queue.
 * @return the number of elements in the queue
 */
public int size()
{
    return count;
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");

}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this queue. 
 * @return the string representation of the queue
 */
public String toString()
{
    String finish = " ";
    Node<String> recent = head;

    while (recent != null){
        finish = finish + (recent.getElement()).tostring() + "\n";
        recent = recent.getNext();
    }
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");
}


  private static class Node<E> {
E element;
Node<E> next;

public Node(E element) {
  this.element = element;
    }
  } 
}
```

JUnit test code:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class QueueT extends TestCase {

        /**
         * The queue to use in all the tests: set this in subclasses.
         */
        protected QueueADT q;

        @Test
        public void testNewQueueIsEmpty() {
            assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(q.size(), 0);
        }

       // @Test
        public void testInsertsToEmptyQueue() {
            int numberOfInserts = 6;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInserts; i++) {
                q.enqueue("zzz");
            }
            assertTrue(!q.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(q.size(), numberOfInserts);
        }

        //@Test
        public void testEnqueueThenDequeue() {
            String message = "hello";
            q.enqueue(message);
            assertEquals(q.dequeue(), message);
        }

       // @Test
        public void testEnqueueThenPeek() {
            String message = "hello";
            q.enqueue(message);
            int size = q.size();
            assertEquals(q.first(), message);
            assertEquals(q.size(), size);
        }

       // @Test
        public void testFiftyInThenFiftyOut() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                q.enqueue(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                assertEquals(((Integer)q.dequeue()).intValue(), i);
            }
        }

       // @Test
        public void testRemovingDownToEmpty() {
            int numberOfRemoves = (int)(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRemoves; i++) {
                q.enqueue("zzz");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRemoves; i++) {
                q.dequeue();
            }
            assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
            assertEquals(q.size(), 0);
        }

       // @Test(expected=NoSuchElementException.class)
        public void testRemoveOnEmptyQueue() {
            assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
            q.dequeue();
        }

        //@Test(expected=NoSuchElementException.class)
        public void testPeekIntoEmptyQueue() {
            assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
            q.dequeue();
        }


}
```

Comment: What lines throw an exception?

Comment: oh sorry. I will edit the post and put the lines!

Comment: okay. done, sorry about that.

Comment: rather than line numbers it would be helpful if you added comments above the exact lines that throw errors (that way we don't have to count line by line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set up method

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    q = new LinkedQueue();
}
```

which will initialize you q object before each test, or

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    q = new LinkedQueue();
}
```

if you want only one shared object between all tests.

On a side note: I don't really see any gains from your custom collection, as a LinkedList seems to fit your goals.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because your `protected QueueADT q;` object is never initialized in `QueueT` class.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a setup() and takedown() method!